# How to solve "The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer" after changing password on Debian/KDE?

Tags: debian, kde, login, password, gnome-keyring

When trying to run a backup with [Vorta](https://github.com/borgbase/vorta) on Debian 10/KDE I'm prompted to enter my password "Enter password to unlock your login keyring" but after entering my current password it displays:

> The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.

After [looking it up](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/) it seems like this is happening because I changed my sudo password.
**-> Why does changing the password not update any other relevant files so that this prompt accepts the current password (why does this error still occur at all)? And what's the simplest, most recommended way to solve it on Debian/KDE?**
I don't have [a .gnome2/keyrings directory](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/problem-with-enter-password-to-unlock-your-login-keyring-889111/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was:

- Install seahorse `sudo apt-get install seahorse && seahorse`
- On the left under Passwords right click on "Login" or a password you'd like to use for Vorta and select "Set as default".
- Verify that the password is the password you'd like to use (and not e.g. a former user password) by selecting "Lock" and then "Unlock" which prompts you for the password.

Further steps for making Vorta work [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624438/how-to-create-a-new-keyring-default-with-kwalletmanager/629189#629189).

(Removing (or moving to have a backup) files under ~/.local/share/keyrings/ only solved this until the next restart. In the case of Vorta I could then create a new backup repository without getting this error but not after a restart.)