# How to create a new keyring "default" with KWalletManager?

Tags: debian, ssh, kde, gnome-keyring, kwallet

I tried running a backup with [Vorta](https://github.com/borgbase/vorta). This failed as I [got the error message "The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer" when trying to do so which is why I (re)moved the keyrings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617679/how-to-solve-the-login-keyring-did-not-get-unlocked-when-you-logged-into-your-c) and initialized a new backup repository. After doing so I could run backups.

However, when I tried to run a backup after a restart I got this prompt asking for a password: "An application wants access to the keyring 'Default', but it is locked" without the password working. I also tried the password for my username which didn't work either. The previously mentioned problem that I linked above may have been caused by changing the password for my user (I didn't get informed about anything breaking by changing the password of my user).

In KWalletManager all the wallets were there again so I deleted them and created a new wallet and made it the default wallet. Then I tried to run the backup. However, even if I initialize a new repository with a new SSH key in Vorta I still get this message without the password working.

**-> How can I see what the "default" keyring is and for example set KWalletManager as the default keyring application instead of for example gnome-keyring (which is also installed)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

- Install seahorse `sudo apt-get install seahorse && seahorse`
- On the left under Passwords right click on "Login" or a password you'd like to use for Vorta and select "Set as default".
- Verify that the password is the password you'd like to use (and not e.g. a former user password) by selecting "Lock" and then "Unlock" which prompts you for the password.

---

- After changing the default password initialize a new backup repository with Vorta. The "borg passphrase" to enter for initializing a new repository is not the same as the default password you selected earlier in seahorse.
- When you click on the password the GUI should list you the saved Vorta passwords once you initialized some repositories.
- You don't need a SSH key if you only do local backups with Vorta.
- Verify that you can also read the backup by going to "Archives" within Vorta, selecting a backup and clicking "Mount", selecting some empty folder and then navigating to that folder and viewing a few files of the backup. If you can read the file and the command below runs through everything should work well.
- Run `borg key export /destination/dir/VortaProfileName/ /dir/tosavekeyin/borgkey-backup` to also backup your borg key to be able access your backup data. Back that up to any media onto which you also backup your data.